# Sharing state among FunctionCompile'd functions

Tags: function-compile

*Understanding that the new Wolfram compiler remains a work in progress:* Global variables apparently aren't accessible from `FunctionCompile`'d functions.  However, passing mutable `DataStructure`s as function arguments provides a way to share program state among multiple compiled functions without needing to copy large state values in and out of functions. I'm okay with that, but are there other practical options?  Should there be?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of the type of problem you are trying to solve? Also I'm not sure what you mean by "copying large state values in and out of functions" - passing arguments to a function (compiled or not) does not create a copy of the data.

Comment: @JasonB I have a simulator processing events with various event handlers. Each handler is a function that must access & modify simulation state in some way. With Hold attributes, state can be passed in variables and modified directly from within the handler - no copying. Without Hold attributes, passing a value involves no copying until the function tries to return a modified value used to Set state, but I know such things are normally done in clever ways that minimize copying. However, for compiled functions, the _only_ comparable approach seems to require mutable DataStructures.